# Visual Studio 2017 C++ Shared Items Project does not recognize STL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am experimenting with the Shared Items projects in VS2017 (Community Edition). (The goal is to create a non-visual library running on Windows and Linux.)

I added a C++ class, and the most standard of include directives for some reason fail. E.g. `#include <iostream>` results in an error. There are some headers in the automatic completion list but they look like proprietary Microsoft stuff.

I had the impression this stuff should work out of the box. For some reason, the Project properties also don't have much going about them, no place to tweak the libraries.

Comment: Do you just get an IDE error, or an actual compiler error?

Comment: A compiler error (as their compilers run in the background when the file is being edited).

Comment: There really isn't information here as is for your problem. You will have to tell us your linker and include directory settings for us to be able to help

Comment: The installer does not install full C++ by default. Try looking at the  "Individual components" tab in the installer for any components you think might be missing

Comment: The compiler does not run in the background. You have to invoke it explicitly. What you see is intellisense. You did use the cpp extension and not c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @RichardCritten, I found that indeed some components were missing (Clang, I believe, although I installed some others). They were not called "standard components" though.

Bad, bad Visual Studio.